# Every so often all the text on The Workplace goes missing

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, design, css

Every so often when I visit the site or even just refresh the page I get the following:

[image: missing text]

All the text is apparently missing.

Highlighting the text or clicking where a link would be show the text and a second refresh usually brings the text back, though at the moment it's being particularly reluctant to appear.

Any ideas what could be happening?

It's happening on Meta too. I just refreshed this question and got exactly the same issue.

Comment: Is this a new issue as of 1 hour ago - or is this something you've experienced since the launch of this site?  I'm not able to reproduce this issue but it might have something to do with rendering our custom font via the CDN.

Comment: I originally got this temporarily when the new site first launched (balpha fixed it). [Here is the part in chat where we discuss it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13893646#13893646). I'm not sure if it's related, but it may well be @Geoff.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas - it's not new. I first saw it just after the site graduated but put it down to caching and the fact that the design had just changed. I've seen it sporadically since. Yesterday was particularly bad.

Comment: Is it possible to capture the request headers for the font file the next time you see this issue?  Specifically the response headers for:  http://cdn.sstatic.net/_fonts/open-sans/opensans-regular-webfont.woff?v=fffe5d363a7c

Comment: @GeoffDalgas - I'll give it a go.

Comment: @ChrisF are you using Chrome, and if so, which version?

Comment: @NickCraver Yep, Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m

Comment: @ChrisF we can repro this too, but *completely* randomly, even partially in the page sometimes fixed on hover - it's definitely a chrome bug you can find details on here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476

Comment: @ChrisF going to status-reproduced this one - this appears to be a bug in chrome which hopefully will go away with future releases.